# Xcode 6 custom font

Tags: ios, fonts

So today I tried to use a custom font in Xcode 6 for the first time and this is what I see for all of them. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?[image]

So I have figured it out that this happens only if I copy font into Xcode. If I only make reference on that font in Xcode and I don't actually copy that into project folder then font is displayed right. Sadly this won't help me because whole app is always copied into a device.

Comment: have you tried to look at the font itself when double clicking on the .otf/.ttf file?

Comment: @bdv font works great. I am using it in photoshop for example. This what you see on picture happened to me with every font I imported into Xcode.